# Enabling I2C on Debian - i2cdetect doesn't show device

Tags: linux, debian, sensors, i2c

I am trying to get my laptop to communicate with my SRF02 sensor, which is using a USB-I2C interface. My laptop is running Debian Jessie.

Problem:

When I run `sudo i2cdetect -y 0` I see no devices at all. This is the same for port 1 but beyond that lots of devices display at random places (eg port 4 shows a nearly full table). At none of the ports < 3 is EX70 taken, which is the device's default location.

I have tried auto loading i2c-dev on startup but the problem persists. The module docs say you need the FTDI VCP driver but this should be included in the Linux kernel.

I am convinced this is a software issue because I was able to get data using the exact same device and setup from a computer running Windows 8.

There are a lot of posts about this already but all of them are specifically Raspberry Pi based, and use the Raspbian and GPIO pins instead of USB.

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Ok thanks for the links, I will try posting on the forums you suggest if this thread receives no answers